# How to get notification if skin changed on spark button

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I have a spark button subclass with a custom skinclass, defined as follows:

```
<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
      skinClass="com.company.NvrControlButtonSkin"
      enabled="false">
```

I have then in the script part of this button subclass a setter for an object, where I register a property listener on that object. In the listener, I need to set a property on the skin itself. However, it happens that the object returned by the `skin` property is not yet of the type I set on the skinClass.
I assume that my property listener is already called before the actual skin is set. I would now like to be notified when the `skin` property is actually changed, so that I then can set the properties on the skin object that are needed.

Is there anything I can listen to or a method that I can override or something to be notified that the skin is actually set to my custom skin now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck, this is an easy fix. `SkinnableComponent` (and hence also `Button`) implements the following two protected methods, which you can override:

- [attachSkin()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html#attachSkin%28%29), called every time a new skin is applied to the component
- [detachSkin()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html#detachSkin%28%29), called when the current skin is removed from the component

That said, I would try to avoid setting properties directly on the skin, because it creates a tight coupling between host component and skin. Try to update properties by using skin parts.